# Git couldn't find remote ref... but I can't either

Tags: git

I have an odd problem with Git where somewhere I have some reference to an old branch called `2013.rel25`, but I have no idea where it is.  This is a branch that was merged and deleted on origin long ago.

```
C:\project>git pull
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/2013.rel25

C:\project>git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master

C:\project>git remote prune origin

C:\project>git pull
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/2013.rel25
```

How can I find out what is referencing this dead branch that exists neither locally, or on the remote?  And then, how can I remove or fix the reference so I can go back to pulling from origin/master to local master?

**EDIT:** My `.git/config` file references it specifically as a fetch head.  I guess I'll just remove it manually:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:somebody/project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = refs/heads/2013.rel25:refs/remotes/origin/2013.rel25
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: I guess, it's specified as merge branch somewhere in the configs. Check `git config --get branch.master.merge`

Comment: @user3159253 Thanks for the note.  I didn't find anything there, but your comment did prompt me to dig into the config file where I found the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to remove this via the command line, so I just edited my Git config file at `.git/config` and removed this line:

```
fetch = refs/heads/2013.rel25:refs/remotes/origin/2013.rel25
```

Comment: Ah, ok :) The keys from `.git/config` may be removed with `git config --unset ...` but `.git/config` is a plain text file and can be directly edited :)

Answer (score -1):

One of way to deal with this problem is to clone the project from remote and you will have Clean files without any errors.